# What are the websites providing medical articles?

Tags: covid-19, research

I'm new here and I'm not sure if my question is off topic, however I need some resources about medical articles concerning the effect of covid on health employees.
I found a website called sci-hub but it's illegal and can't access it in UE.
I just want to know if there are some resources providing medical articles for free.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several open access journals and collections that you can search.

- The [Journal of the American Medical Association (JAMA) Open Access network](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamanetworkopen).
- The [New England Journal of Medicine allows open access to certain articles](https://www.nejm.org/about-nejm/access-levels).
- [Several journals in the Lancet family are open access](https://www.thelancet.com/open-access).
- The British Medical Journal has an open access counterpart, [BMJ Open](https://bmjopen.bmj.com/).

Also, for many articles, the authors will happily share a copy with you if you email them and ask politely. Since they're busy, it might take a while for them to reply, but at least with academics, many are happy to share their work.

Comment: thanks forr those links

Answer (score 2):

- [**PubMed**](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) comprises more than 32 million citations for biomedical literature from MEDLINE, life science journals, and online books. Citations may include links to full text content from PubMed Central and publisher web sites.

After you search using the search box on the main web site, select in the left column this filter:
`text availability: free full text`.

- [**PubMed Central**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/) (PMC) is a free **full-text** archive of biomedical and life sciences journal literature at the U.S. National Institutes of Health's National Library of Medicine (NIH/NLM).

Answer (score 1):

It's often useful to search on a big database (like [PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/)) to find articles you're interested in, then next try to figure out how to access them.

Answer (score 0):

- [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) is another good place to try to find a freely available PDF for a given article.
- https://www.medrxiv.org/: preprints of medical papers
- https://www.biorxiv.org/: preprints of biology papers
- https://connect.medrxiv.org/relate/content/181: COVID-specific articles.